# Azure download VHD fails

Tags: azure

I just lost access to an Ubuntu VM on azure, and I am attempting to download the VHD to another VM to recover data from the disk.

I'm using the azure command line tool to accomplish this. I've imported the publishsettings file and am able to view the VMs/storage accounts. However when I attempt to download the vhd the transfer always fails. The error I'm getting is

```
error:   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
error:   storage blob download command failed
```

To me this sounds like a connectivity issue, but I can't understand why this would happen when transferring to a VM on azure. I ran the command using debug mode to see if this would provide more information, and it seems that it retries the connection about 30 times when it first fails. The file transfer seems to fail at different points, sometimes reaching as much as 3GB (out of 30), other times failing after a few hundred MB.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

While it is unfortunate this is happening (you should contact Azure support for this), the recommendation for coding would be to catch the ENOTFOUND and retry downloads. Of course, if you feel that this is unacceptable (since the failure occurs 30 times or more), invoking Azure support is your best bet.

Comment: I'm not using the API (question is a bit ambiguous I realise), just the command line tool. If I were to use the python API, is there functionality to resume a partial download?

Comment: Not sure, you would have to look at the source for this API :(

You may also try a tool like CloudXplorer or Azure Management Studio to try downloading the blob.

Answer (score 0):

are you using Unmanaged Disk? then you should use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). I see that's good choice for you.

In my experience, I chose Azure Storage Explorer after upload fails many time via Azure Web Portal, not using Azure command line like you. My VHD have 32GB, then it always corrupted upload.